# Ambiguous column name error when upgrading to Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sqlexception

The code below worked fine in Rails 3 but it throws an error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: 
id: SELECT "categories".id FROM "categories" 
INNER JOIN "categorizations" 
ON "categories"."id" = "categorizations"."category_id" 
WHERE "categorizations"."reason_id" = 283 ORDER BY id
```

The problems seems to be the call to reason.category_ids

```
- reasons.each do |reason|
  - cat_ids = reason.category_ids.map {|id| "cat_id_#{id}"}.join(" ")
  %li{"data-reason-id" => reason.id, :class => cat_ids}
    %a= reason.text

class Reason < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations
```

UPDATE:
When commenting out the last line here the problem is fixed. is it a bug?

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :reasons, :through => :categorizations

  scope :active, where("active = ?", true)
  default_scope :order => 'id'
```

Comment: Where are you doing the ordering? `ORDER BY id` is the ambiguous part as both `categories` and `categorizations` have an id column I presume.

Comment: it seems the problems is

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
default_scope :order => 'id'

How can I fix it?

Comment: Does `default_scope :order => 'categories.id'` resolve it?

Comment: commenting it out resolves the original issue. but what was wrong? all worked well in Rails 3.o . how do i default_scope it correctly in 3.1?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot answer that... all my scopes have been doen in 3.1 and later. I only grabbed the id thing by looking at the SQL in the error.

Comment: Took some digging but found it... see answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here we go](http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface)...

```
[In Rails 3.1] Supplying options hash to with_scope, with_exclusive_scope and default_scope has also been deprecated:

default_scope :order => "id DESC"
```

[Try](http://matthewhutchinson.net/2010/9/22/rails-3-ambiguous-column-name-and-multiple-order-scopes):

```
default_scope order('categories.id')
```